# open/execute Outlook's Custom flag dialog popup with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2013, office-2013

Within Outlook 2013, if you want to add a custom flag to an item you get this dialog:

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to open this dialog using VBA? I can either open it for a selected e-mail item or if there is a way to open it directly and retrieve the date/data the user selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simulate pressing buttons with [ExecuteMso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419.aspx)

```
Private Sub AddReminderDialog_ExecuteMso()

    Dim objItem As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Err <> 0 Then
        ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder")
    Else
        ActiveExplorer.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("AddReminder")
    End If

End Sub
```

You can see the "AddReminder" when you hover over the button when adding to the Quick Access Toolbar or a ribbon.

Comment: That is great. Thank you so much!!